# how to resolve Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core - 8.10.0.1 nuget installation error

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

Error Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\vivek.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.1\lib\xamarinios10\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Has already installed package Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations и Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core version 8.10.0.1, if remove packages and try to restore - return error
Unable to find version '8.10.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations'
Error downloading 'Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations.8.10.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.firebase.ios.installations/8.10.0.1/xamarin.firebase.ios.installations.8.10.0.1.nupkg'.
Could not find a part of the path

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and ended up using version `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core - 8.10.0` .

**UPDATE:**

Shorten the installation path. see: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/555#issuecomment-1145943195

Answer (score 3):

I want to post the solution directly for other people

1. closed vissual studio
2. created path C:\Nuget
3. added env variable "C:\Nuget" to NUGET_PATH
4. added env variable "C:\Nuget" to NUGET_PACKAGES
5. downloaded nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
6. copied it into the solution folder and into C:\Nuget
7. opened a command window and navigated  to my project solution (cd ...)
8. nuget restore MySolution.sln
9. re open the solution and I can install all the nuget packages

Comment: This fixed it for me, but I had to add "C:\Nuget" to "PATH" as well

Answer (score 1):

Disable Maximum Path Length Limitation by following this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

**Summary**

1. Set
   HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled
   to 1
2. Restart the machine or it wont work