# Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFireStore 8.10.0.3 Nuget installation error while using Plugin.Firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

Facing below mentioned error when using Plugin.Firebase package in .NET7 MAUI. Unable to build the project and make push notification work in the app due to this issue.

**Error MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Nuget\xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\tsi\alts\zero_copy_frame_protector\alts_grpc_integrity_only_record_protocol.h" to "bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\tsi\alts\zero_copy_frame_protector\alts_grpc_integrity_only_record_protocol.h". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed**.

Tried out all the workaround suggested related to this issue but nothing works. Is anyone still facing this issue ?

[how to resolve Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core - 8.10.0.1 nuget installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473203/how-to-resolve-xamarin-firebase-ios-core-8-10-0-1-nuget-installation-error)

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/555

https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob/issues/1

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/639

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/640

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/555

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.11.4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue is because of the long path limitation on windows OS. u will not have this issue if you are using visual studio on macos.

the work around is to manually build your project using command prompt. you can type this in the Package Manager Console:

dotnet build --framework net8.0-android

dotnet build --framework net8.0-ios

after that you can debug using visual studio.